# How to chain requests synchronously with axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

Suppose I have in my code several places with something like

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: myurl,
  data: mydata
}).then(...)
```

I would like the various axios requests to be executed synchronously : the next one must wait for the `then` callback of the previous one before it is sent to the server.

It seems that what I ask is exactly what promises can offer you (by chaining several `then`, say). Since Axios is Promise based, I suppose it should somehow be able to do that. But oddly enough, I cannot find this information anywhere.

Note that I do not know in advance all the requests to be sent : there is a first one, then a second one might arrive before the first one finishes, or not, and so on.

ADD ON : Also I think I see how to achieve what I ask by making the Promises myself, sending directly Asynchronous Http Requests. It just seems weird that the library designed for that would not offer this possibility.

Comment: The same way you would chain any Promise - inside the `.then`, return the next axios call

Comment: `synchronously` - you mean serially, because synchronously implies something else

Comment: I may mean serially then. @CertainPerformance : I don't understand what you mean. Note that the various requests are made in various places of the code.

Comment: Are you just trying to send data in sequence? Or does the next request depend on the response of the previous request?

Comment: It sounds like you may want queuing if the requests are spawned arbitrarily but must always execute serially. However, such a requirement is suspicious. Provide more information

Comment: The data of the next request may depend on the previous request. As an exemple, some request add something in the database, server-side, and send back a primary key, that will then be reused inside further requests, whose purpose if to modify what we added. Do you think this is suspicious ?

Comment: How are the requests being "queued"? You say one may come in before the other finishes, but also say that some requests depend on the response of others, it's very confusing. You should provide more code so it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: The order of the requests depend on user actions. If the user add something, then he can modify it right after on the user interface. However, as I said, uploading the modifications should be done only after the adding request is fully completed. Is it more clear ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the "add" requests fails after a "modify" request is queued? How are you able to modify something that hasn't been added? Are multiple things being added and modified simultaneously? Please update your question with more detail specific to your problem and provide actual example code, the current example does nothing to explain your problem.

Comment: If the add request fail, I want to display an error message, and of course in this case the modification is not possible. I do not have any code yet : I like to know how to do something before I do it. For that, I'm looking for an answer to this theoretical question : Does axios provide the feature of executing serially various requests that may come from various user actions ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did not know the following : if the return of the function passed as parameter to a `then` call returns a Promise, then this promise is resolved before further `then` calls. Concretely, I think the following achieve what I want :

Once, at the beginning of the script:

```
let requestSender = Promise.resolve('');
```

Then whenever I need to send a request :

```
requestSender.then(prev => 
    axios({method: 'post', url: myurl, data: mydata}).then(...))
```

that way, each new axios request will wait for the previous one to end before being sent.